# Set previous on the basis of month passed dynamically

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date

In my function, I am passing a month's name as param to fetch the data. I need to perform operation: `Get the first and last dates of the month previous to the month passed.`

I am stuck at achieving the same.

Here's the dynamic function I am working with:

```
module.exports = function (monthname) {
  const months = [
    "january",
    "february",
    "march",
    "april",
    "may",
    "june",
    "july",
    "august",
    "september",
    "october",
    "november",
    "december",
  ];

  const current = new Date();

  const month = months.indexOf(monthname.toLowerCase()) + 1;

  return {
    prev_month_first:
      new Date(Date.UTC(current.getFullYear(), month - 1, 1)) /
      1000,
    prev_month_last:
      new Date(Date.UTC(current.getFullYear(), month, 0)) / 1000,
  };
};
```

Controller.js

```
export_previous_month = (req, res) => {
const { monthname } = req.params;
  const previousMonth = getPreviousMonth(monthname);
  console.log('march exprected', new Date(previousMonth.prev_month_first * 1000), new Date(previousMonth.prev_month_last * 1000))
}
```

Suppose I pass 'April' as a parameter to the function, it should output `March 01 and March 31` as the previous month respective to `April`. But instead, it gives April's first and last dates only. 
If `March` is passed as param, it should return the first and last dates of `February`.

Please help to rectify the issue.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Can you help me by including an example?

Comment: You need to pass the year as well since getting the dates for February differs in leap years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module.exports = function (monthname) {
  const months = [
    "january",
    "february",
    "march",
    "april",
    "may",
    "june",
    "july",
    "august",
    "september",
    "october",
    "november",
    "december",
  ];

  const current = new Date(new Date(new Date().setDate(15)).setMonth(months.indexOf(monthname)));
  const prev_month_last = new Date(current.setDate(0));
  const prev_month_first = new Date(new Date(prev_month_last).setDate(1));  
  return {
    prev_month_first, prev_month_last
  };
};
```

Comment: @E F both `prev_month_first, prev_month_last` are printing the same first date of march now.

Comment: Sorry, just fixed above

Comment: Can you explain a bit for my future understanding, why we need to pass new Date () method as a parameter inside the first new Date() method?

Comment: Where `new Date()` is run on say the 31st of a month and the month to get has fewer days (say 30), then setting the month will roll over to the 1st of the next month, so setting the date to 0 gets back to the original month, not the month before.

Comment: @RobG, OMG, fixed above. But please tell me how you managed to find it?

Comment: @bubble-cord,
`new Date()` // returns current date object.
`new Date().setDate(15)` // sets the 15th of this month but returns it not as a date, but as a number of milliseconds. To convert milliseconds back to Date object we need to pass it to another new Date.... and so on

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very close, you just messed up with setting the month: you don't need to subtract 1 from the month index when getting the last of the month as the month name array is already zero indexed:

```js
function getPreviousMonth(monthname) {
  let months = ["january","february","march","april","may","june",
    "july","august","september","october","november","december",
  ];
  let current = new Date();
  // Don't add 1 to month index
  let month = months.indexOf(monthname.toLowerCase());
  return {
    // Don't use Date.UTC, truncate decimal part
    prev_month_first:
      new Date(current.getFullYear(), month - 1, 1) / 1000 | 0,
    prev_month_last:
      new Date(current.getFullYear(), month, 0) / 1000 | 0      
  };
};

let timeValues = getPreviousMonth('march');

// Show timeValues (seconds)
console.log(timeValues);

// Show as dates
Object.keys(timeValues).forEach(key => 
   console.log(key + ': ' + new Date(timeValues[key]*1000).toString())
 );
```

By using the Date constructor the way you have, you avoid issues with the built–in parser (always a good idea), and also don't mess with *current* once it's created, which helps, and don't get into strife with different length months. Wins all round. :-)

Oh, and don't mess with Date.UTC as then you introduce issues with timezones around midnight near the end of the month.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You gave quite a clear explanation. One doubt if you can clear that too. I used a similar approach to get `the first and last day of the current month.` But When I tried it in the browser's console, it prints the result as expected, i.e. 1st April 2020 and 30th April 2020 (was performing that code last month), but testing it in the postman environment, gives the wrong result. After I added UTC, it worked fine in postman too. But here, you're telling to add UTC. Can you tell this behavior?

Comment: Usually you should work either entirely in UTC or entirely in local unless you have a very good reason to mix the two. The above will work if you use Date.UTC, getUTFullYear, setUTCMonth, etc. so if you want everything in UTC, do that. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Ever heard of [moment js](https://momentjs.com/docs/)?

Take a look how easy things can be.

```js
const getDate = (monthname) => {

  const months = moment.months().map(month => month.toLowerCase())

  const current = moment().subtract(1, 'months');

  const month = months.indexOf(monthname.toLowerCase()) + 1;

  return {
    prev_month_first: current.startOf("month").toDate(),
    prev_month_last: current.endOf("month").toDate()
  };

}

console.log(getDate("april"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am aware of it, but don't want to achieve using core JS date method available. :)